# Regression Discontinuity on Stata with a discrete assignment variable and excluded data at the cutoff

Tags: regression, stata, discrete-data, threshold, regression-discontinuity

I am looking at a treatment effect of an intervention on a cutoff of age, where age data is only available discrete as year of birth. Due to this, people who turned the cutoff age during the study period have to be excluded, as you cannot tell if they are in the intervention group or the control group. I have a dummy variable which highlights whether they received the intervention or not.

Due to this exclusion and discrete data, it is necessary to extrapolate up to the threshold from the models above and below the threshold. I want to use local polynomial regression.

Any help would be much appreciated.